# how to put text in middle of two words in php

Tags: php

I am editing a HTML file with Php but when i tried to write some text in between the body tag

it should look like:

`<body>Hello</body>`

but my code is doing this:

`<body><hello`

php file:

```
fwrite($myfile, $html);
$page = strpos($html, "body>");
$pagei = (int)$page + (int)"6";

fseek($myfile, $pagei);
fwrite($myfile, "hello");
```

I am new in php, i searched internet all day but didn't find anything on how to fix this.

Comment: You can't insert text into a file like you do in an editor, for instance. When you're writing in a file at a given position, you're erasing what was previously at this position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_replace('<body></body>', '<body>Hello</body>', $allText);
```

or consider adding placeholders:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{content}
</body>
</html>
```

and then:

```
str_replace('{content}', 'Hello', $allText);
```